# how to print value which pointer member pointing to in C

Tags: c

I have a struct

```
struct c
{
    int *id;
    int type;   

} obj;
```

how to print what `obj.id` pointing to? and also point `obj->id` to some int variable

I tried

```
printf("%p\n",obj.id);
```

but above is printing some address

and

```
printf("%d\n",obj.id);
```

in above compiler gives warning

```
format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

Comment: You need to dereference it: `printf("%d\n", *obj.id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dereference the pointer:

```
printf("%d\n",*(obj.id));
```

Answer (score 7):

Since `obj.id` is a *pointer* to an `int` (an `int*`) you need to dereference it (using the `*` operator).

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct c {
    int *id;
    int type;   
} obj;

int main() {
    int x = 10;
    obj.id = &x;
    printf("%d\n", *obj.id);
}
```